# so I have done a linear search code but when i input a number thats in the array it still gives prints (number has not been) why is that?

Tags: python, linear-search

hi so i have to do linear search program and I have done it here

```
def linearsearch(arraydata,num):
    flag = False
    for i in range(0,len(arraydata)):
        if num == arraydata[i]:
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    return flag
arraydata = [10,5,6,7,1,12,13,15,21,8]
num = int(input("please input the number you want to find: "))
returnvalue = linearsearch(arraydata,num)
if returnvalue == True:
    print("number has been found")
else:
    print("number has not been found")
```

but whenever I input a number which is the array it still says number has not been found please anyone's help would be appreciated

Comment: That's not binary search.

Comment: yes im sorry i chnaged it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method only returns true if the last item is equal to the value because you are overwriting the flag on each iteration. You should return `True` immediately after the value is found and return `False` at the very end, after the loop.

```
def linearsearch(arraydata, num):
    for x in arraydata:
        if x == num:
            return True
    return False
```

You can directly use the `in` operator to perform the same task.

```
def linearsearch(arraydata, num):
    return num in arraydata
```

Comment: ohhh ok I get it now thank you so much appreciate the  help it works now :)

Comment: @RishabhKalia No problem.

Comment: @RishabhKalia If this answers your question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

don't update the flag at every check.

```
def linearsearch(arraydata,num):
    flag = False
    for i in range(0,len(arraydata)):
        if num == arraydata[i]:
            flag = True
    return flag
arraydata = [10,5,6,7,1,12,13,15,21,8]
num = int(input("please input the number you want to find: "))
returnvalue = linearsearch(arraydata,num)
if returnvalue == True:
    print("number has been found")
else:
    print("number has not been found")
```